# Azure AD is not returning token : Unknown Host Error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to grant access to **IoT Hub** based on **Azure AD**. But when I try to get token, it is throwing this error in **Postman**
[image]

**####### Update ######**
I have already created the Application in Azure AD
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `resource` field should be the static ID of all IoT Hub service principals. Try this instead of the hostname:

```
89d10474-74af-4874-99a7-c23c2f643083
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

I created an Azure AD application like below:

[image]

To generate token via Postman, I used the below parameters:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/token

client_id:14ad98e6-8b3d-4774-a2ad-XXXXX
client_secret:XXXXXX
resource:https://iothubs.azure.net
grant_type:client_credentials
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the above token, I can see the **aud** as **`https://iothubs.azure.net`** like below:

[image]

The **400 Bad request** error usually occurs if you have passed any invalid URL while generating the token. Make sure to pass the valid parameters.

Try sending the request again in Postman and check if the access token is generated or not.

Alternatively, you can also replace the resource by **`89d10474-74af-4874-99a7-c23c2f643083`** as suggested by Matthijs van der Veer like below:

[image]

**Decoded token Response:**

[image]

Comment: Hello, I have updated the question. i.e I have already created the Azure AD and gave the same credentials. Though I am getting the same error

Comment: Try replacing the resource by 89d10474-74af-4874-99a7-c23c2f643083

Comment: I tried that too, same error